# Compatible partitions with laws of compositions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integer-partitions

An exercise from Artin's Algebra:

> Let S be a set with a law of composition: A partition $\Pi_1 \cup \Pi_2 \cup ...$ of S is *compatible* with the law of composition if for all i and j, the product set
>
> $$\Pi_i \Pi_j = \{xy \mid x \in \Pi_i, y \in \Pi_j\}$$
>
> is contained in a single subset $\Pi_k$ of the partition.
>
> (a) The set $\mathbb Z$ of integers can be partitioned into the three sets [Pos], [Neg], [{O}]. Discuss  the extent to which the laws of composition $+$ and $\times$ are compatible with this  partition. 
>   (b) Describe all partitions of the integers that are compatible with the operation $+$.

A) Yes for $\times$. No for $+$ because $4+-2=2 \in$ [Pos] but $5+-7=-2 \in$ [Neg]

B) This is an introduction to the next section on Modular Arithmetic. Some partitions are $\{\mathbb Z/\mathbb Zn\}_{n \ge 0}$. As Arturo Magidin points out, other partitions are $\{ \{a + \mathbb Zn\}_{a \in \mathbb Z} \}_{n \ge 0}$ (I'm actually not sure about the notation)

Am I correct?

Comment: I think so, but of course (b) does require some work.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thank you! I have a proof, but I didn't quite see the need to write it. I just wanted to know if I am right.

Comment: Actually, I expect the partitions considered will be $a+n\mathbb{Z}$, $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ for a fixed $n$. What you have described is a family of partitions (each $n$ gives you a partition, if you interpret $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is the partition corresponding to $n$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin About the $a +n \mathbb Z$, thank you! About the family of partitions, what did I say? $\mathbb Z$ is a partition, $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$ is a partition, $\mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z$ is a partition, etc. They are partitions. I think I used the wrong notation, but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: @JackBauer: You gave a set, and the elements of that set are partitions. I expected you meant to give a partition (a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ that form a partition), as opposed to giving a set of partitions. I would have said “I expect the partitions to be the $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$” or some such, rather than give a set (which makes it seem like you are trying to describe a partition, given the context).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh thank you for settling that. I think I know how to describe your partitions now too. I will edit my post after this comment.

Comment: @JackBauer: No, I don’t think you understood what I meant.  The partition of $\mathbb{Z}$ that you will consider when looking at arithmetic modulo $n$ is going to be the partition $\{a+n\mathbb{Z}\mid a\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. The component sets of the partition are the sets $a+n\mathbb{Z} = \{ a+nk\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Each value of $n$ gives you a different partition, and when considering modular arithmetic, you typically only do one modulus at a time, so only one partition at a time.

Comment: @JackBauer: It is true that if you were to consider **all** moduli at the same time you would have a countable number of partitions, one for each modulus. The partition corresponding to a single $n$ can be denoted $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (though then you have issues that this notation also represents the group/ring structure that can be placed on the partition sets); so as you consider different moduli, you’ll consdier different partitions. But you’re almost never going to want to consider all of these many partitions at the same time. So you won’t care about the set of all of them.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'll be thinking about those later. Thank you. But for now $\mathbb Z / \mathbb Z1$ is a partition, $\mathbb Z / \mathbb Z2$ is a partition, etc correct?

Comment: @JackBauer *kind of*. In general, if $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on the set $X$, then $X/\sim$ denotes the partition induced by $\sim$. $n\mathbb{Z}$ (not $\mathbb{Z}n$) is a subgroup/ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, which induces an equivalence relation, which induces a partition; and we use $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (abusing the notation somewhat mightily) to denote both the partition induced by the equivalence relation induced by $n\mathbb{Z}$, and also the algebraic structure we can define on that partition.